# Delta-equal to symbol

Tags: symbols, relation-symbols

How do you write the equal-to symbol with delta on top ("delta-equal to")? One similar to http://www.decodeunicode.org/de/u+225c. Are special packages required for that?
It is supposed to be used for definition of equalities, similar to `:=`.

Comment: Try `$\overset{\Delta}{=}$`.

Comment: `\triangleq`, after `\usepackage{amssymb}`

Comment: @egreg, when is this \triangleq used? what is it for?

Comment: @NathanB No idea. I’ve never used it myself.

Comment: Defines an equality. Google knows this too.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

How about `\triangleq` from the AMS fonts?  Loading `\usepackage{amssymb}` will make the command available

Comment: actually, `\usepackage{amssymb}` is needed for this.  while `amsmath` loads `amsfonts`, not all the symbols are "named" unless `amssymb` is loaded explicitly.

Answer (score 10):

EDITED to ensure rendering of the `=` in math mode.  For more flexibility in the vertical placement, than the `\overset` (which requires `amsmath` package), you could try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\delequal{\mathrel{\ensurestackMath{\stackon[1pt]{=}{\scriptstyle\Delta}}}}
\begin{document}
$a \delequal b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

The optional argument to `\stackon` specifies the vertical gap between symbols.  If you wanted the delta smaller, you could add `\scriptscriptstyle` in place of the `\scriptstyle`:

[image]

For comparison, here is `$a \overset{\Delta}{=} b$`.  Note the vertical offset is significantly larger than what I proposed.

[image]

Comment: Maybe illustrate the `\overset{}{}` just to compare.

Comment: Thanks for the exhaustive answer, I really appreciate it, I'll keep this in mind when creating other stacked symbol monstrosities, but today the simpler `\triangleq` saves the day (and my latex refuses to download stackengine.sty for some reason).

Comment: Understood.  Best wishes.  FYI, the package is at http://ctan.org/pkg/stackengine

Comment: I needed `$=$`, not `=`, as in `\def\delequal{\mathrel{\stackon[1pt]{$=$}{$\scriptscriptstyle\Delta$}}}` to get a correct result, since the first argument of `\stackon` appears to be rendered in text mode just like the second. At least, with `=` the output looks wrong and different.

Comment: @Blaisorblade Thank you for pointing that out.  For some fonts, there is no difference I think, but to guarantee math mode rendering, I have updated the answer.