# How to enlarge triangleq with Minion Pro?

Tags: fonts

I am using Minion Pro and when I define equation I write equal sign as `\triangleq` but it comes out tiny. How to make it larger?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[conference,onecolumn,14pt]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[mathlf,footnotefigures,minionint,textlf]{MinionPro}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{Myriad-LF}
\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1 
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}

\begin{document}

My equation is:
\begin{align}
  F\left(\mathbf{X},
  \mathbf{Y}\right)\triangleq\dfrac{\det\left(\mathbf{X}^\top\mathbf{Y}\right)}{\log\Tr(\mathbf{X})},
  \text{ if } \Tr(\mathbf{X})>0.
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

which gives me:

[image]

Now, as you can see, the triangle above the equal sign is really small. How to make it larger?

I can do an alternative solution by calling `\coloneq` instead of `\triangleq` but I prefer the triangle equal sign instead.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: See at link http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163829/delta-equal-to-symbol. There is a similar question.

Comment: the font you're getting this symbol from is `MnSymbol` (not `Minion Pro`), which tends to have quite small symbols in general.  other fonts have more intelligible forms of this symbol.  check them out in the "comprehensive symbols list" (`texdoc comprehensive` and search for `triangleq` to see what's available).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this, with `stackengine`?

```
\documentclass[conference,onecolumn,14pt]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[mathlf,footnotefigures,minionint,textlf]{MinionPro}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{Myriad-LF}
\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}
\newcommand{\bigtriangleq}{\mathbin{\setstackgap{S}{0pt}\stackMath\Shortstack{\smalltriangleup\\ =}}}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine} \begin{document}

My equation is:
\begin{align}
  F(\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{Y})\bigtriangleq \frac{\det(\mathbf{X}^\top\mathbf{Y})}{\log\Tr(\mathbf{X})},
  \text{ if } \Tr(\mathbf{X})>0.
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]